# PyQt5 set QTextEdit document margin (constantly)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to set a permanent margin in QTextEdit. And I found out about `self.document().rootFrame()`. I tried to set the left and right margin, however, the placeholder text is not adapting the margin same with clearing the text using `self.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `QTextDocument::setDocumentMargin()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop, which you can access by calling `QTextEdit::document()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document, or `QTextEdit::setViewportMargins()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins. I am not sure which one will work best in your case. You need to try it.

Comment: Viewportsmargin is what I'm looking for. My follow up question is how about set the lineheight? I tried to use the `textCursor().blockFormat().setLineHeight()`. However if I paste something, it doesnt apply.